# Wordpress Shortcode Not Rendering

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I'm trying to create a custom shortcode to render a button. Is the code I have here correct?

```
function rb_button($atts) {
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
      'color' => '#000',
      'txtcolor' => '#FFF',
      'url' => '#',
), $atts));

return '<button class="btn btn-default" style="background-color:'.$color.'; color:'.$txtcolor.';" onclick="window.open(\''.$url.'\')" >'.do_shortcode($content).'</button>';    


add_shortcode('rbbutton', 'rb_button');

}
```

Then I'm inserting [rbbutton]Text Here[/rbbutton] in the post. But it's just rendering it as text.

Comment: Just put add_shortcode('rbbutton', 'rb_button'); outside the function.

Comment: Oh my goodness...something so simple that caused me so many hours of anguish. Thanks @WisdmLabs!